# How to detect which part of an image has been touched, when image is rotated?

Tags: android, bitmap, touch, image-rotation

I have an image like this one. I can rotate it using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414819/android-rotating-an-imageview-with-finger-moves-other-views-around). Now I would like to know, which color has been touched, independently of the wheel's position. For example, whatever of the following positions the wheel is in, I should be able to detect what color I have touched ...red, yellow, green,blue,pink or grey.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Is there any other possibility instead of using a single picture?(solution I would prefer to avoid...)

[image]  or [image] or [image] or whatever...

UPDATE: I post some colors because I wanted to be more clear, and I got a solution for this, but how could I do if I have different images instead of a color.

Answer (score 4):

Decode the x & y position of the touch event then call getPixel on the Bitmap:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: +1 Yes, very good answer for my question.Shame to ask but...how do I do if I have different images or texts instead of colors? and I can't call `getPixel`

Comment: Build a list of regions for the image before rotation.  Your program will rotate the image by applying a transformation.  Apply the reverse transformation to the touch event's x,y location and compare the the original regions.

Comment: I saw something similar on SO. The solution they found was to overlay the circle with images (text, whatever) with circle of colors. And then go the amb's way