# Updated: Rotate a bitmap that exceeds screen size

Tags: android, matrix, touch, image-rotation

My image is bigger, but just a part of it have to be displayed on the screen. I have done this. My problem is that, the image has to be rotated by finger. The code below works as it should on a small image. But on my image it has a wrong behave, repositioning the image up and down and rotate it     weirdly. How to make my image to rotate normally?, as a small image. Then I have to be able to get the color touched. I get an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933130/how-to-detect-wich-part-of-an-image-has-been-touched-when-image-is-rotated), but I still have to work at it. But first, please tell me how could I solve the problem with rotation, and if you have ideas about the second issue, with getting the color touched I would like to hear them.

this is the image:

[image: this is the image]

this is how it should appear on the screen:

[image: this is how it should appear on the screen]

**XML Layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/roata"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code**:

```java
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
    picture.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
}

public android.view.View.OnTouchListener onTableTouched = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt)
    {
        double r = Math.atan2(evt.getX() - picture.getWidth() / 2, picture.getHeight() / 2 - evt.getY());
        int rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);


        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            //
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
           updateRotation(rotation);
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            //
        }

        return true;
    }
};

private void updateRotation(double rot)
{
    float newRot = new Float(rot);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roata);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(newRot - 50);

    Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    picture.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Because I got nowhere with `Bitmap` and `Matrix` I tried to adjust the `RotateAnimtaion()` to get something as similar as I could. I think modifying the second param and the duration of the animation dynamic, we can get a similar result without changing the Y position.   Now, the problem is that the image is crop, I think because of `scaleType="center"`. I will post code and a screen shoot. Could this be improved?

```
Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, param,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    a.setFillEnabled(true);
    a.setFillAfter(true);
    a.setDuration(param);

  picture.startAnimation(a);
```

[image]

Comment: Try with  android:scaleType="fitXY" instead of   android:scaleType="center"

Comment: @Aerrow.. `scaleType=fitXY` is stretching the image, and I don't want this, but I have tried it anyway and I get the same behave

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is , you are trying to redraw the same Bitmap in every updateRotation() call.

How about removing this line,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roata);
```

from `updateRotation(double rot)` and have it declared globally , so that you need not create the same Bitmap again and again which is why you are getting the OutOfMemory.

Try this,

```
Bitmap bitmap=null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roata);
    picture.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
}


public android.view.View.OnTouchListener onTableTouched = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
        double r = Math.atan2(evt.getX() - picture.getWidth() / 2, picture.getHeight() / 2 - evt.getY());
        int rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
           updateRotation(rotation);
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //
        }

        return true;
    }
};

private void updateRotation(double rot) {
    float newRot = new Float(rot);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(newRot - 50);

    Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    picture.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
}
```

Comment: It has the same weird effect. The image is moving(translate effect) up and down when try to rotate it, changing its Y position, this is what annoying me most. Then the image tend to came in the initial position.

Comment: Looking very carefully, it seems that the rotation itself get the Y translation,even with a little image but at least the small image is rotating, the big one ....

Answer (score 1):

just declare Bitmap as globally  as:

```
private WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmap;
```

and use

```
bitmap =new WeakReference(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roata));
```

instead of

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roata);
```

Comment: If i do this, I can't use anymore `bitmap.getWidth()` and `bitmap.getHeight()` in `updateRotation()`

Comment: @AlexAndro : WeakReference if another way to avoid memory Leaks.if your application is running by @ Andro answer then fine but you must try to declare Bitmap as WeakReference